# How should the parameters for axios look like according to the url example

Tags: javascript, url, axios, request

I have this URL. How can I translate it into params for axios?

`customer?$select[0]=id&$select[1]=firstName&$select[2]=lastName&$select[3]=email&$skip=0&$sort[createdAt]=-1&email=test@email.com`

```
const { data } = await this.request({
      method: 'get',
      url: `/customer`,
      params: {
        // ?
      },
    });
```

Comment: `{"$select[0]": "id", etc}`

Comment: @JaromandaX What about email with value?

Comment: Same ... key:value just like the others. You're creating a javascript object. It's not any more complex than that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually simply by setting a property with a key and value.

```
params: { email: "test@test.com" }
```

In cases where the key contains special characters, which are not allowed for property keys in JS, you can set the key in quotation marks

```
params: { "$select[1]": "firstSame" }
```